# How to insert data from selected rows according to row number?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a jinternal frame form with jtextfields. these textfields getting name and admission no as values.In database table where the name & admission no is stored has more attributes like dob,contact no  and so on. 
So i need to type select query to select  specific rows in table and need to insert values to that particular rows.

I have found to select specific rows  in database from this site.

```
select * from <table name> LIMIT 6,10  --(if i need row 6 to 16)
```

To insert values into table i typed

```
"select * from addstu LIMIT 2,1 insert into (firstName,lastName,admissionNo) values ('"+fn+"','"+ln+"','"+no+"')" ;
```

But error has occured in

```
"insert into  (firstName,lastName,admissionNo) values ('"+fn+"','"+ln+"','"+no+"')" ;"
```

i can't find the error

Please help me

Comment: insert query to above code?

Comment: i am getting values from jtext field and i select rows which i need from above query . how to insert values i am getting through jtextfield into database

Comment: The query syntax `"select * from addstu LIMIT 2,1 insert into (firstName,lastName,admissionNo) values ('"+fn+"','"+ln+"','"+no+"')" ;` is wrong. Correct and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 limit 6,10;
```

Comment: i am getting values from jtextfield and i need to know how to insert values that iam getting from textfield into database